# Android: Insert only new records from Server(Google sheet) to Client (SQLiteDatabase)

Tags: android, json, sqlite, google-sheets-api

Currently , In Android - i am able to get complete data from Google Sheet and insert into Sqlite Database using Content Providers (bulk Insert) . (fetching Data via AsyncTask)

Problem is: I want to only insert new records which are available in Google Sheet and not in Sqlite Database. 
Unique combination in Database and excel sheet is Date + City

Can someone guide me on how to achieve this? Please

Any existing example is highly appreciable. As i am bit new to Android Development.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, Found the Solution by linking dots.

Get Latest Record Date from database. Pass that Parameter to Google Spread Sheet JSON URL

Now JSON result will give only the data which is not available in Database.